# FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, setstate

FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.)

When I sign up and get the value from FirebaseAuth to save to Firebase Cloud Firestore but I can't resolve this issue.

```
My sourcecode:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function()? onTap;
  const RegisterScreen({super.key, required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  //text editing controllers
  final emailController = TextEditingController();

  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  //sign user up method
  void signUserUp() async {
    //show loading circle
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });

    //try creating the user
    try {
      //check if password is confirmed
      if (passwordController.text == confirmPasswordController.text) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: emailController.text,
              password: passwordController.text,
            )
            .then((value) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(value.user?.uid)
                    .set({
                  "UID": value.user?.uid,
                  "email": value.user?.email,
                  "joinDate": DateTime.now().toString(),
                }));
      } else {
        //show error message, password don't macthing
        // showErrorMessage("Password don't match!");
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Password don't match!", gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER);
      }
      // pop the loading circle
      // error this here
      //--------------------//
      Navigator.pop(context);
      //-------------------//
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      //pop the loading circle
      //show error message
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage(e.code);
    }
  }

  void showErrorMessage(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 68, 17),
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                message,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 20),

              //logo
              Image(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),
                width: 140,
              ),

              // const SizedBox(height: 1),
              //'Let\'s create an account for you'
              Text(
                'Let\'s create an account for you',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 10),

              //username text field
              MyTextField(
                controller: emailController,
                hintText: "Email",
                obscureText: false,
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              //password text field
              MyTextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                hintText: "Password",
                obscureText: true,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              //Confirm password text field
              MyTextField(
                controller: confirmPasswordController,
                hintText: "Confirm Password",
                obscureText: true,
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 20),

              //sign in button
              Mybutton(
                text: "Sign Up",
                ontap: signUserUp,
              ),
              //or continue with
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Divider(
                        thickness: 0.5,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                      child: Text('Or continue with'),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 10),

              //google + facebook sign in buttons
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  //google button
                  Squaretile(
                      onTap: () {},
                      // onTap: () => AuthService().signInWithGoogle(),
                      imagePath: 'assets/images/google.png'),

                  const SizedBox(width: 5),

                  Squaretile(
                      onTap: () {}, imagePath: 'assets/images/facebook.png'),
                ],
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 10),

              //not member? register
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Already Have a account?",
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 4),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: widget.onTap,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Login now',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code there are two point which might cause this error.

1. When you are calling the FirebaseAuth you are using both await & then. You should use only one of this.

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: emailController.text,
       password: passwordController.text,
       ).then((value) =>
```

2. When you there is any `Firebase` error you are popping the page & then trying to show the message alert.

```
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      //pop the loading circle
      //show error message
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage(e.code);
    }
```

Here your message alert is on signup page & you are popping the page before showing the alert. This causing the code to try showing the alert on signup page without the signup page.
You should only show the error without going back.